# Create new user with foreign key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm looking to see if my implementation is correct/efficient when creating a new identity 2.0 user which has a foreign key restraint. I've extended the Identity properties to include an OrganisationId foreign key for a One-to-Many relationship to my Organisation table.

My demo application has been setup so that each user is assigned to an Organisation for multi-tenant purposes. Many users can interact with the data associated with their assigned organisation.

I've modified the standard **Register** post method in the Account Controller like so *(my modifications are contained within the #Region tags)*:

```
// POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [LayoutInjector("_LayoutLogin")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            #region Create New Organisation Record
            //Initialize DB Context
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            //Flag to determine if a new account was created
            bool newOrganisationCreatedFlag = false;

            //Check if Organisation already exists
            if (model.OrganisationId == null)
            {
                //Create new Organisation object
                Organisation organisation = new Organisation(model.OrganisationName);
                //Add new Organisation to db conext
                db.Organisation.Add(organisation);
                //TODO Implement error above for failed creation of new Organisation
                //Save new Organisation to db - Throw error & return if fails
                if (await db.SaveChangesAsync() <= 0)
                    return View(model); //Error Required 

                //Set new Organisation flag
                newOrganisationCreatedFlag = true;
                //Set new Organisation Id to User Model
                model.OrganisationId = organisation.Id;
            }
            #endregion

            //Create new User
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, OrganisationId = model.OrganisationId };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //  Comment the following line to prevent log in until the user is confirmed.
                //await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                string callbackUrl = await SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account");

                // Uncomment to debug locally 
                // TempData["ViewBagLink"] = callbackUrl;

                ViewBag.Message = "Check your email and confirm your account before you can log in.";

                //return View("Info");
                return View("RegisterConfirmEmailMsg");
                //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            #region User Creation Failed. Delete New Organisation From DB
            //Failed to create new User. Delete newly created Organisation
            if(newOrganisationCreatedFlag == true)
            {
                Organisation organisation = await db.Organisation.FindAsync(model.OrganisationId);
                db.Organisation.Remove(organisation);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            #endregion

            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Simply I do the following:

- Create a new Organisation record (this step is skipped if an Organisation already exists)
- Create the new User passing the OrganisationId property
- Delete the **new** Organisation record if the creation of a new user fails (this step is skipped if the Organisation was created previously)

Again, I'm simply wondering if this is a good/bad approach and all feedback is welcome.

Comment: `ApplicationUser` should also have a property `Organisation`. You can set it by a new or existing organization (attacheded as Added or Unchanged, resp.) and everything will be saved smoothly in one call.

Answer (score 0):

Would not be more correct to use transaction?

Here are examples:

- [How to create transaction with asp.net identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32858014/how-to-create-transaction-with-asp-net-identity)
- http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3087/how-to-work-with-transactions-in-aspnet-mvc

In your case:

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
using (var trans = db.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
{
  try
  {
 //Check if Organisation already exists
        if (model.OrganisationId == null)
        {
            //Create new Organisation object
            Organisation organisation = new Organisation(model.OrganisationName);
            //Add new Organisation to db conext
            db.Organisation.Add(organisation);
            //TODO Implement error above for failed creation of new Organisation
            //Save new Organisation to db - Throw error & return if fails
            if (await db.SaveChangesAsync() <= 0)
                return View(model); //Error Required 

            //Set new Organisation flag
            newOrganisationCreatedFlag = true;
            //Set new Organisation Id to User Model
            model.OrganisationId = organisation.Id;
        }

        //Create new User
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, OrganisationId = model.OrganisationId };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            //  Comment the following line to prevent log in until the user is confirmed.
            //await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

            string callbackUrl = await SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account");

            // Uncomment to debug locally 
            // TempData["ViewBagLink"] = callbackUrl;

            ViewBag.Message = "Check your email and confirm your account before you can log in.";

            //return View("Info");
            return View("RegisterConfirmEmailMsg");
            //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
          trans.Rollback();
        }
catch (Exception ex)
{
  trans.Rollback();
  Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
}
```

}