# How to create transaction with asp.net identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I am doing registration on which i am asking for 5 things:

**FullName,EmailId,Password,ContactNumber,Gender**

Now emailid and password i am storing with register method and given in below two link:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

            using var context = new MyEntities())
            {
                using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var DataModel = new UserMaster();
                        DataModel.Gender = model.Gender.ToString();
                        DataModel.Name = string.Empty;
                        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);//Doing entry in AspnetUser even if transaction fails
                        if (result.Succeeded)
                        {
                            await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Role.ToString());
                            this.AddUser(DataModel, context);
                            transaction.Commit();
                            return View("DisplayEmail");
                        }
                        AddErrors(result);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        return null;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

public int AddUser(UserMaster _addUser, MyEntities _context)
    {
        _context.UserMaster.Add(_addUser);           
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return 0;
    }
```

Now with this below 2 lines:

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);//entry is done in AspnetUsers table.
await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Role.ToString());//entry is done is Aspnetuserrole table
```

Now this Fullname,contactno,gender i am having in another table that is **UserMaster**.

So when **i will submit my registration form i will save this details** in **UserMaster and AspnetUsers,AspnetUserinrole table**.

But consider if there any problem occurs while saving record in UserMaster then i dont want to save entry in Aspnetuser and Aspnetuserinrole too.

**I would like to create a transaction where i would rollback if any problem occurs during saving any record in any table i.e no entry should be done in AspnetUser,AspnetUserinRole nd userMaster.**

Records should be saved successfully only if there is no problem in saving record in this 3 tables otherwise whiole transaction should be role back.

**I am using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity for login,Register,role management and other and following this tutorial**:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset

http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity

But as await UserManager.CreateAsync and UserManager.AddToRoleAsync method are built in method how would i synchonize it to work with entity framework.

So can anybody guide me how to create such transaction or anything that would solve this?

**IdentityConfig**:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };

            // Configure user lockout defaults
            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

            // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
            // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                Subject = "Security Code",
                BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
            manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }

    // Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
            : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
        {
        }

        public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
        }

        public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not create a new db context, but use the existing one.

```
var context = Request.GetOwinContext().Get<MyEntities>()
```

It is created per request if you use default implementation.

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
```

**Update:**

OK, since you are using two different contexts your code will look something like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

        var appDbContext = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
        using( var context = new MyEntities())
        using (var transaction = appDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                var DataModel = new UserMaster();
                DataModel.Gender = model.Gender.ToString();
                DataModel.Name = string.Empty;

                // Doing entry in AspnetUser even if transaction fails
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Role.ToString());
                    this.AddUser(DataModel, context);
                    transaction.Commit();
                    return View("DisplayEmail");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}

public int AddUser(UserMaster _addUser, MyEntities _context)
{
    _context.UserMaster.Add(_addUser);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return 0;
}
```

Here, `appDbContext` is the same context that is used by `UserManager`.

Comment: Can you please extend your ans and try to fit this in to my code because this is the first time i am using this owin and mircosoft identity.so its a request that you please provide somewhat detail ans.

Comment: Its my own mvc template but code i am using from that 2 link only which i have provided in my question

Comment: See my updated code and I am using Database first entity approach

Comment: Really this worked like a charm.Genius.How did this work?i am not getting it.Can you please make explain me??

Comment: dbContext used by UserManager is created once per request. By calling HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>() we are getting the reference to the same instance used by UserManager and not creating the new one

Comment: can i ask u 1 small question please??

Comment: In my usermaster i am having Id,Fullname,Email etc fields.Now during login i would use SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync in which i will get result that this email is correct or not and if i got result true then i will use this email id and i will find user with this email from my usermaster and fetch id and i will store this id in session and after login i will use this id(from usermaster).Is this correct procedure or it would be more better if you could suggest me any good approach as i am using this code for the first time.Please

Comment: It really depends on what are you trying to build.. Basically you should know that you don't have to create separate class for storing additional user data - you could just extend ApplicationUser class and add what ever properties you need. Furthermore you can extend ApplicationDbContext and add to it all needed tables and use it all over the application

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90973/discussion-between-learning-and-aleksey-l).

Comment: Can this answer be updated for .NET Core 2.1 or higher?  The following code does not exist for 2.1: HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();.  Am I missing something? @Learning-Overthinker-Confused

Comment: @KyleBarnes Sorry this was not EF core.I was using Entity framework EDMX

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it with [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Role.ToString());
        string callbackUrl = await SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account");
        return View("DisplayEmail");
    }
    scope.Complete();
}
```

So, both actions will be done in one transaction and if method `Comlete` does not call, both actions will be canceled (roolback).

If you want to solve it with EF only (without TransactionScope), you need to refactor your code. I don't know implementation of class `UserManager` and methods `CreateAsync` and `AddToRoleAsync`, but I guess that they creates new DBContext for each operation. So, first of all, for all transactional operations you need one DBContext (for EF solution). If you add this methods, I'll modify my answer according to EF solution.

Comment: Please see my updated question with updated code but still entry is created in AspnetUser though transaction fails because CreateAsync and AddToRoleAsync has nothing to do with entity framework still i am not so sure about this.

Comment: @Backs `UserManager` takes a `UserStore` and `DbContext` is a constructor dependency in the latter. So Identity does not create a context for you - it is already a single context

Comment: Using transaction scope did not work for me... `UserManager.CreateAsync` times out everytime

Comment: Even changing all Async calls to the Sync ones, it did not work. Bummer...

Comment: Worked for me once I added:
var transaction = new TransactionScope(System.Transactions.TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);

Seems UserManager functions all use async methods at the lowest level, so this must be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Backs alternative works for me, when i use this method: TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions