# How can i commit in identity aspnetusers table and another table in one transaction

Tags: asp.net-core, transactions, asp.net-identity

i have two tables one is identity table aspnetuser and other is the user table that i have created now one of the column in aspnetuser is identity column autogenerated and this is the foreign key in aspnetuser table and primary key in user table ultimately creating one-one relationship.
now i have this need where i want to insert in these two tables at the same time so if after creating record in aspnetuser succeeds but creating record in users table fails i need to rollback the changes.
how can i achieve this? because for now              `await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);`
this piece of code enters record in aspnetuser table as soon as its called...
i found something similar here [How to create transaction with asp.net identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32858014/how-to-create-transaction-with-asp-net-identity) but can't get my head around it as in my case aspnetuser table has a U_ID column which is identity column generated by db and i need to get its value to create a new record in user table
is it even possible?
here's the diagram
[one-one relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLf6Q.png)

and here's the application user

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [PersonalData]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int U_ID { get; set; }
    }
```

UPDATE
as told by @Zhi Lv i tried this

```
returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
                var result = false;
                var errorlist = new List<IdentityError>();
                ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
                var user = new ApplicationUser();
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                  
                        using (var transaction = _dbcontext.Database.BeginTransaction())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                                ShortGuid sguid1 = guid;

                                //insert user to Users table.
                                var customeruser = new OnlineEarning.Core.DataModel.Models.User()
                                {
                                    Name = Input.UserName, 
                                    Password = Input.Password, 
                                    Email = Input.Email,
                                    UserRefNo = sguid1,
                                    EasyPaisaNoJazzCashNo = "2214457896",
                                    PhoneNo = "2214457896",
                                    City = "Rwp",

                                };
                                _dbcontext.Users.Add(customeruser);
                            _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                                //get the latest user id.
                                var u_id = customeruser.Id;
                                //
                                user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email, U_ID = u_id };

                                var saveresult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                                if (saveresult.Succeeded)
                                    result = true;
                                else
                                    errorlist = saveresult.Errors.ToList();

                                transaction.Commit();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                transaction.Rollback();
                            }
                        }
                      
                    if (result)
                    {
                        //do something
                    }
                    foreach (var error in errorlist)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                    }
                }

                // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
                return Page();
```

but now i am getting this exception `'Execution TImeout expired'`

**UPDATE 2**
now i am able to create a transaction and enter records in both table in single transaction with below code

```
  try
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            var result = false;
            var errorlist = new List<IdentityError>();
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            var user = new ApplicationUser();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                    using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope(System.Transactions.TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                            ShortGuid sguid1 = guid;

                            //insert user to Users table.
                            var customeruser = new OnlineEarning.Core.DataModel.Models.User()
                            {
                                Name = Input.UserName,
                                Password = Input.Password,
                                Email = Input.Email,
                                UserRefNo = sguid1,
                                EasyPaisaNoJazzCashNo = "01224457854",
                                PhoneNo = "01224457854",
                                City = "Rwp",

                            };
                            _dbcontext.Users.Add(customeruser);
                            _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                            //get the latest user id.
                            var u_id = customeruser.Id;

                            user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email, U_ID = u_id };

                            var saveresult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

                        if (saveresult.Succeeded)
                        {
                            result = true;
                            var uservs = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
                            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                            var userv = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
                        }
                        else
                            errorlist = saveresult.Errors.ToList();

                             transaction.Complete();
                       
                    }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                             transaction.Dispose();                   
                            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.InnerException.Message.ToString());
                    }

                    }
              
                if (result)
                {
                    //do something
                }
                foreach (var error in errorlist)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Page();
        }
```

but during debugging i found out i was unable to read or write to both the tables  in sql server when transaction was started in debugging..now my question is what if two users try to register at the same time?will only one of them be allowed and other one will get exception?if yes then what to do in this kind of situation...offcourse transaction is must cannot avoid it otherwise data would be inconsistent

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, only one column per table can be configured as `Identity`, so, in the `ApplicationUser` class, since it inheriting from the `IdentityUser` (it already contains the identity column), even you configure the U_ID as Identity, the database will not generate a value when a row is inserted. Besides, according to the diagram, it seems that you want to configure one-to-one relationship between the aspnetusers table and Users table, if that is the case, I suggest you could try to set the Identity column in the Users table, and use the following code to configure relationships:

User.cs:

```
public class User
{
    [Key] 
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int U_ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUser.cs:

```
public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    public int U_ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("U_ID")]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    #pragma warning disable CS0114 // Member hides inherited member; missing override keyword
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    #pragma warning restore CS0114 // Member hides inherited member; missing override keyword
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Then, when register the user, you could refer to the following code to use transaction and insert data.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager; 
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public RegisterModel( UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,  ApplicationDbContext context )
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager; 
        _context = context;
    } 
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    { 
        var result = false;
        var errorlist = new List<IdentityError>();
        var user = new ApplicationUser();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    //insert user to Users table.
                    var customeruser = new User() { PhoneNo = "12345678", Name = "Tom", Password = "Password01", Email = "tom@hotmail.com" };
                    _context.Users.Add(customeruser);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    //get the latest user id.
                    var u_id = customeruser.U_ID;
                    //
                    user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email, U_ID = u_id };

                    var saveresult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password); 
                    if (saveresult.Succeeded)
                        result = true;
                    else
                        errorlist = saveresult.Errors.ToList();

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
            }

            if (result)
            { 
                //do something
            }
            foreach (var error in errorlist)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
}
```

The result like this:

[image]

Reference:

[Entity Framework Core Transaction](https://entityframeworkcore.com/saving-data-transaction)

[Using Transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions)

[One-to-One Relationship Conventions in Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-one-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx)

**[Update]**

In your scenario, you could insert the AspnetUser first, then get the U_ID and insert a new item into the Users table, please try to change the code as below:

```
        var result = false;
        var errorlist = new List<IdentityError>();
        var user = new ApplicationUser();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email }; 
                    var saveresult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

                    if (saveresult.Succeeded)
                    {
                        result = true;
                        //get the U_ID
                        var userid = user.U_ID;
                        //use the U_ID to create user.
                        var customeruser = new User() { U_ID = userid, PhoneNo = "12345678", Name = "Tom", Password = "Password01", Email = "tom@hotmail.com" };
                        _context.Users.Add(customeruser);
                        _context.SaveChanges();

                    }
                    else{
                        errorlist = saveresult.Errors.ToList();
                    }
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
            } 
            if (result)
            {
                //do something
            }
            foreach (var error in errorlist)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }
```

Comment: your method will work too but about identity column i think you misunderstood..aspnetuser table doesn't have any identity column so the U_ID column which i have created is actually the one and only identity column in aspnetuser table and its working fine if i enter a new record it works but only issue is that i want to get this U_ID value from aspnetuser table and then create a new record in user table with this U_ID and then only coomit to database if both succeeds otherwise rollback

Comment: Hi @Jazz, Please check the update, in your scenario, could insert the AspnetUser first, then get the U_ID and insert a new item into the Users table.

Comment: hi i have actually already tried that but it enters the record in aspnetuser table as soon as createasync method is called so transaction doesn't really happens there...thanks for the effort though

Comment: now after i tried the method you told before i am getting this exception 'Execution TImeout expired' on this line                                 var saveresult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
i think its locking the table 
but can't figure out why this exception is coming

Comment: Can't reproduce the Execution Timeout expired exception, perhaps as you said, the table was locked. Try to use create a new aspnetuser via the dbcontext, instead of using UserManager.CreateAsync method. Besides, from your description, it seems that if add the user first (then, add the aspnetuser), it works well. For the concurrency conflict issue, you could try to add [Concurrency Tokens](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations)(ConcurrencyCheck or Timestamp/rowversion), and refer [this article](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/concurrency).